# What does the key param do in an computed properties set and get?

Tags: ember.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  fullName: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', {
    get(key) {
        return `${this.get('firstName')} ${this.get('lastName')}`;
    },
    set(key, value) {
        let [firstName, lastName] = value.split(/\s+/);
        this.set('firstName', firstName);
        this.set('lastName', lastName);
        return value;
    }
  })
});
```

Considering this example, why would one have a need for the key param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` returns the property name, `fullName`. It is generally not needed when you are defining a computed property. It is sometimes useful if you are writing a computed property macro. I usually leave it out.

Guide docs for computed with get/set: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties

Here's an example usage from Ember source: [deprecatingAlias](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/cc9568b4985429ee69eb77e114362747cf8c6be8/packages/ember-runtime/lib/computed/computed_macros.js#L671)

Comment: IMHO, the question is not about what is `key`, it is about why someone should need it. You said "It is sometimes useful if you are writing a computed property macro". I guess the question owner needs an exact, valid example about this. Can you show an example of how it is useful while writing a macro?

Comment: Example added as requested